# Session Storage Variable after Page Redirect (using AngularJS route)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, redirect, port, angular-local-storage

I have a scenario where I have a logon page (this will later move to the SAML2 identity provider server). After successful authentification the user will be redirected to a different server (this will host the main application).

For testing purposes I am running 2 nodejs instances on my localhost (one on port 8080 and the other on port 8050). In the login-application I am setting the session/localstroge parameter as follows:

```
on 'http://localhost:8080';

$rootScope.globals = {
                currentUser: {
                    username: username,
                    authdata: authdata
                }
            };

...

$window.localStorage.setItem('globals',  JSON.stringify($rootScope.globals));
```

and later after success the redirection to:

```
window.location.href = 'http://localhost:8050';
```

From here I would like to access the session or localstorage:

```
console.log($window.localStorage.getItem('globals'));
```

But the variable is 'null'.

BTW cookieStore works without problem ...

So my question, is there a limitation specifically for session/localstorage when I redirect to a different url (or in this case port of localhost)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not just redirecting the application to another URL.
You are also changing the port, so, obviously, you are changing the application context.

Since `sessionStorage` or `localStorage` are application-dependent, you cannot access them from another context.

Comment: Thanks all! This confirms what I thought.

Answer (score 2):

Any data stored is tied to the document origin, in that it’s tied to the specific protocol being used (`http` or `https` etc.), the host (e.g. `html5doctor.com`) and the port (usually/implicitly port `80`).

Thus, changing any part of the origin results in also changing the data store context.

Answer (score 1):

This is a domain problem. Build a reverse proxy server and hide your real server behind it, so that the following occurs

```
# Request origin » Actual path
#
localhost/api    » localhost:8080/api
localhost/data   » localhost:8085/data
```

Now the browser only sees `localhost` as the host and your application should work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are going from **http://localhost:8080** to **http://localhost:8050**,
that means you are loading another page/document.

Therefore `localStorage` can't store your data, as it uses the `same-origin` policy to determine access rights to the stored data.

Answer (score 0):

If you redirect it to different node instance your session and local storage will not work, as it depends on the application and in your case you are changing the application on redirection so your data is lost.